# Объединение дубликатов, при наличии ссылок на них

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, например, `City`:

```
------------------
 Id | Code | Name
------------------
```

И зависимая таблица `User`

```
------------------
 Id | City | Name
------------------
```

`User.City` это `FK` для `City.Id`.

Мне нужно объединить все города, у которых одинаковый `Code` (т.е. удалить дубли). При этом пользователь должен перейти в новый, уже единственный с таким кодом, город. Я могу найти дублирующие коды:

```
SELECT Code FROM City
GROUP BY Code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Но никак не могу придумать, как этим воспользоваться.

Comment: DISTINCT пробовали? Или какое то из полей все же уникальное среди дублей?

Comment: Кажется, это ваш случай: http://www.sql-ex.com/help/select18.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполните запрос

```
;WITH
d1 AS (
    SELECT
        Id, Code,
        Cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Code),
        Num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Id)
    FROM City
),
dupCities AS (
    SELECT Code, Num, Id
    FROM d1
    WHERE Cnt > 1
)
SELECT df.Id as IdFrom, dt.Id as IdTo
INTO #Mapping
FROM dupCities df
    JOIN dupCities dt on dt.Code = df.Code and dt.Num = 1
WHERE df.Num >= 2
```

получите временную таблицу `#Mapping`, согласно которой обновите записи в таблице `User`:

```
UPDATE U
SET U.City = M.IdTo
FROM [User] U
    JOIN #Mapping M on M.IdFrom = U.City
```

После чего можно удалить дубликаты в `City`:

```
DELETE FROM City
WHERE Id IN (SELECT IdFrom FROM #Mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

В результате выполнения вашего запроса вы получите массив дублей городов, потом пробежавшись по массиву через for получаете и удаляете все записи по Id, за исключением первого или последнего елемента

Comment: Циклы в Transact-SQL работают намного медленнее запросов. Плохой совет. Посмотрите запрос, который написал i-one.